# Multiple disjoint subset sum problem

Tags: algorithms, integer-programming

Given two sets of nonnegative integer numbers:

$X = {x_1, x_2, ... x_n}$
$Y = {y_1, y_2, ... y_m}$

Need to find partition of $X$ on $m$ disjoint subsets, such as sum of elements in $i$-th subset equal to $y_i$.

This generalization of [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is known to be **NP-Complete**. One of the probable way of solving is to reduce it to [system of integer linear equalities](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92470/0-1-solution-to-system-of-linear-integer-equations). But it's even more general and really hard to solve task. May be one has some fresh ideas?

Comment: You might synchronize your indices.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.03.28

Comment: you may want to post this on http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have several questions about this problem.
I have already had a decision procedure for this problem, but I call it multi-target subset sum problem. It is my research topic.
I wonder that where did you encounter this problem or any application about this.
Maybe we can discuss it here or in email.
Thank you!
My email: dokelung@gmail.com

Answer (score 4):

http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0020-0190(00)00010-7

Comment: This paper is directly available at http://www.or.deis.unibo.it/alberto/mssp_g_f.ps